# MySql select, need to add to my statement

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have a statement to select active items from database, but with that I would also like to make it select items that starts with name BlueBall.

My current code:

```
$query = "SELECT ShortName FROM product WHERE Active = 1";
```

Comment: Ok, I dont know why so many down votes, but thanks to those who answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```sql
SELECT ShortName FROM product WHERE Active = 1 OR ShortName LIKE 'BlueBall%'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT ShortName FROM product WHERE Active = 1 AND ShortName LIKE 'BlueBall%'
```

Comment: I interpreted "*I would also like to make it select items that starts with name BlueBall*" to mean "*in addition to...*".  I suppose the OP might have mis-spoken, though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `like` condition like this:

```
$query = "SELECT ShortName FROM product WHERE Active = 1 AND ShortName like 'BlueBall%'";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ShortName FROM product WHERE Active = 1 AND ShortName LIKE "BlueBall%"
```

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html

Answer (score 0):

Just add name to `where` clause with OR operator
Here is the rewritten query:

```
$query = "SELECT ShortName FROM product WHERE Active = 1 OR name like 'BlueBall%';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ShortName FROM product WHERE Active = 1 OR ShortName LIKE 'BlueBall%'
```

would work.
 http://w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp